# Getting - UserNotFoundException - while calling adminCreateUser - AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am having a very peculiar issue regarding User creation in AWS Cognito.
When I am in the same region (e.g US-East-AWS and Creating User from NA) then it is working like a charm. 
But when someone is in other region (e.g US-EAST-AWS and creating user from EU with a slow internet connection) then I am getting `UserNotFoundException`.

Below is the how I am handling User creation in my Lambda function (JS)

```
await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params).promise()
if (customer.MFA === true) {
   await toggleCognitoUsersMFA(jsonBody.email, true)
}
```

Comment: You can give it a go. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=243504

Comment: Could you please show us how the `params` looks like? What is exactly in the payload?

Answer (score 13):

Check your `MessageAction` value in your params.

If the value is set to `RESEND`, and you're creating a new user, you'll get this User Not Found message.

The current AWS docs indicate that either a `RESEND` or `SUPPRESS` value is required, this is not true, you can actually omit the value.

Comment: This is a silly error message. Of course the user is not found, I want to create it, the function name is 'admin_create_user'. And as you said, the docs are really not clear about this field.

Comment: Haha yeah thought the same thing. I'm like wait. I want to do exactly that, create a user that isn't found. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻